# Как можно удалить разный текст на php?

Tags: php

Нужно удалить этот текст полностью

```
<div class="b-list__item-comments">
    Комментарии: 0
</div>
<div class="b-list__item-tags">
    Теги: Высшая хоккейная лига, Ижсталь (Ижевск)
</div>
```

Но здесь постоянный текст только `Комментарии:` и `Теги:`, остальное меняется

Знаю как удалить постоянный текст,

```
$content = str_replace('Комментарии:','', $content);
```

А как остальное?

Comment: `preg_replace` и регулярные выражения вам в помощь

Comment: Всё, что в `div` и сам `div` не проще удалить?

Comment: Class одинаковые